# (Three.JS) How to loop lerp scene background colors?

Tags: javascript, loops, colors, three.js, lerp

as the title says, I'm trying to smoothly transition between multiple colors. (Day, Sun Rise/Set, and Night,), and have these colors as the background for my scene, essentially, I'm trying to make a Day/Night Cycle. Is this possible? If so, how?
I'm also wondering, is it possible to add GUI into Three.JS? I'm talking about in the [Three.JS Editor](https://threejs.org/editor/), by the way. Thanks!
Here's the test code, along with everything I've tried so far. Obviously, none of which have worked.

```js
var day = new THREE.Color(0xB8F4FF);
var duskdawn = new THREE.Color(0xFF571F);
var night = new THREE.Color(0x17012D);

//scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xB8F4FF);



/*
//cycleloop();
function cycleloop(){
    var day = new THREE.Color(0xB8F4FF);
    var duskdawn = new THREE.Color(0xFF571F);
    var night = new THREE.Color(0x17012D);
    var clock = new THREE.Clock();
    clock.start();
    var speed = 10;
    var delta = 0;
    delta = clock.getDelta();
    var col = new THREE.MathUtils.lerp(day, duskdawn, 0.1);
    //scene.background.setColor(new THREE.MathUtils.lerp(day, duskdawn, delta));
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(new THREE.MathUtils.lerp(day, duskdawn, delta));
    requestAnimationFrame(cycleloop);
    //renderer.render(scene, camera);
}

cycleloop();
*/
function cycletime() {
  var time;
  //scene.background.setColor(new THREE.MathUtils.lerp(day, duskdawn, time));
  scene.background = new THREE.Color(new THREE.MathUtils.lerp(day, duskdawn, time));
}
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  cycletime();
}

/*
let then = 0;
function animate(now) {
  now *= 0.001;  // make it seconds

  const delta = now - then;
  then = now;

  object.position.z += delta * speedInUnitsPerSecond;

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}
requestAnimationFrame(animate);
*/

//vartween = new TWEEN.Tween(day).to(duskdawn, 5000).start();

//scene.background.setColor(new THREE.MathUtils.lerp(day, duskdawn, 0.1));
//scene.background.setColor(tween);
```

If anyone needs any more information, please, let me know!
Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You are not perform the linear interpolation correctly. Try it with this code instead:

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

let t = 0;

const day = new THREE.Color(0xB8F4FF);
const duskdawn = new THREE.Color(0xFF571F);

init();
animate();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.z = 1;

  scene = new THREE.Scene();
  scene.background = new THREE.Color();

  const geometry = new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry(0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
  const material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
    antialias: true
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

}

function animate() {

  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  t += 0.01;

  scene.background.copy(day).lerp(duskdawn, 0.5 * (Math.sin(t) + 1));

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.123/build/three.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. This is what I'm looking for, but I have one question; how would I make it also have a night cycle?

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for this. But one approach that allows you to interpolate between an arbitrary count of colors is to setup a color keyframe track like in this example (https://threejs.org/examples/#misc_animation_keys) and then use animation system to animate the background.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I'm wondering, are there any other ways of doing this? Also, I did say in my question that I was trying to transition between colors for Day, Sunrise/Sunset, and Night.

Comment: Do you know of any others?

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to achieve having a Day, and Night, Cycle, using Lerp, or something other than animation keys?

Comment: I'm still looking for a way to do this.